# React Native SyntaxError ","

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

Receiving syntax error,  SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ",". It is for the third to last line ");"

I am having trouble seeing where I need to insert the ",".  I have tried in front of the ); and after. No luck. This is while I was adding the code for google sign in for ios.  Would appreciate any assistance.

```
    render() {
        LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
        const scrollEnabled = this.state.screenHeight > height;
        return (this.state.logedin ?
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>
                <ScrollView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview}
                    scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
                    onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
                >
                    <ImageBackground source={require("/Users/carloscraig/NoExcusasRN/screens/assets/grassbcg2.png")}
                        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                        <Image source={require("/Users/carloscraig/NoExcusasRN/screens/assets/noexlogo.png")}
                            style={styles.logo}>
                        </Image>

                        <Text style={styles.greeting}>{'BIENVENIDO!'}</Text>

                        <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                            {this.state.errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.form}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>correo electrónico</Text>
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    autoCapitalize="none"
                                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                ></TextInput>
                            </View>

                            <View style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
                                <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>contraseña</Text>
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    secureTextEntry
                                    autoCapitalize="none"
                                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                ></TextInput>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                            <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500" }}>Iniciar Sesión</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <SafeAreaView style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <Image style={{
                                width: 300,
                                height:300,
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignSelf: 'center'
                            }} source={{uri: this.state.photo}} />
                            <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
                            <Text>{this.state.email}</Text>
                            </SafeAreaView>:
                            <SafeAreaView style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center'
                            }}>
                            <GoogleSigninButton
                                style={{ width: 192, height: 48 }}
                                size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
                                color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
                                onPress={this._signIn}
                                disabled={this.state.isSigninInProgress} />
                        </SafeAreaView>

                       <TouchableOpacity
                            style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 32 }}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ color: "#414959", fontSize: 13 }}>
                                No tienes una Cuenta? <Text style={{ fontWeight: "500", color: "#E9446A" }}>Regístrate</Text>
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>


        );
   }
}
```

Comment: at line 4, remove `?` and place `&&`

Comment: well that took the error away, and for some reason now my screen is just entirely white, it does not change or anything, just white, could this have something to do with that part of the code?

Comment: yeah `this.state.logedin` is returning false. If you want to display alternate thing on `false`, you use `? :` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

React [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn
        ? <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
        : <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You need to add the other half (false case) to the ternary. In this case if you do not want to render anything you need to return `null`.

```
render() {
  LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
  const scrollEnabled = this.state.screenHeight > height;
  return (this.state.logedin ?
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"></StatusBar>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview}
        scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
        onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
      >
        <ImageBackground source={require("/Users/carloscraig/NoExcusasRN/screens/assets/grassbcg2.png")}
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
          <Image source={require("/Users/carloscraig/NoExcusasRN/screens/assets/noexlogo.png")}
            style={styles.logo}>
          </Image>

          <Text style={styles.greeting}>{'BIENVENIDO!'}</Text>

          <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
            {this.state.errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
          </View>

          <View style={styles.form}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>correo electrónico</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                value={this.state.email}
              ></TextInput>
            </View>

            <View style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
              <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>contraseña</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                secureTextEntry
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                value={this.state.password}
              ></TextInput>
            </View>
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500" }}>Iniciar Sesión</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <SafeAreaView style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}>
            <Image style={{
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignSelf: 'center'
            }} source={{ uri: this.state.photo }} />
            <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.email}</Text>
          </SafeAreaView>:
                    <SafeAreaView style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}>
            <GoogleSigninButton
              style={{ width: 192, height: 48 }}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
              onPress={this._signIn}
              disabled={this.state.isSigninInProgress} />
          </SafeAreaView>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 32 }}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: "#414959", fontSize: 13 }}>
              No tienes una Cuenta? <Text style={{ fontWeight: "500", color: "#E9446A" }}>Regístrate</Text>
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    : null);
}
```